# Почему не применяются правки в CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Сделал себе сайт на WP, чуть допиленный чужой шаблон. Меняю CSS а сайт абсолютно не меняет вид. В чем может быть проблема? [Вот сайт](https://morepsd.com/).

**UPD.** Уже и important писал, и что только не делал. Как будто стили перебиваются каким-то другим.
Кеш очищен, перегрузка страницы по <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>

Сейчас прописал в коде `body {color: #aaa !important; }` ему абсолютно все равно

**UPD2.** Да я не такой лох же :) в теле страницы пробовал, меняется, но только через пару тройку дней

**UPD3.**
Ребята, спасибо за версии, нашел где собака порылась. Это все из-за кеширования на стороне cloudflare, я запускал ssl и прочие плюшки через него. Вопрос закрыт!

Comment: В том что вы кеш не чистите, Либо как то не правильно меняете. У вас не хватает конкретики в вопросе

Answer (score 1):

Потому что на данном сайте нет никакого текста, который размещен непосредственно внутри body. Все находятся в своих элементах, которые имеют свой заранее заданный класс и свой цвет. Если для теста добавите `<style> *{color: #F00} </style>` - должно сработать (звездочка выделяет вообще всё, что есть на странице и крайне редко бывает нужна).

И убедитесь, чтобы не перепутали `class` и `id`

Одинаковый класс может быть у многих элементов. Классы выделяются через точку `.class {}`, а id - уникальное имя конкретного элемента и он не может быть одинаковым у нескольких элементов. id в CSS выделяется через клетку `#id {}`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

!important попробуй дописать

```css
BODY {
/* Черный цвет текста, повышенная важность */
color: #000 !important; 
}
```

Попробуй свой файл ксс позднее поставить чем основной и допиши ипортант

Answer (score -1):

Темы могут брать css из многих мест. Могут, например, на лету компилировать sass писать его в кэш, а уже оттуда брать css. Если вам нет необходимости изменять много css, откройте настройщик темы (если тема его поддерживает), это можно сделать через "админ панель->внешний вид->настроить", перейдите на вкладку "дополнительные стили" и пропишите там ваш css. Эти стили имеют приоритет над другими стилями темы. Не забудьте сохранить изменения.